# Attributes sqlite-net doesn't work

Tags: c#, attributes, windows-phone, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I don't know if this problem it's related that I'm using SqliteNetExtensions but attributes here seems to work partially.

I.E. if I declare a column with [Ignore] attribute I see that in my table the attribute exist, so the attribute here it's not considered.

But in other columns, where I'm using TextBlobbed decoration, it seems to work because SqliteNetExtensions serialize it.

Can somebody explain me why and how to make Ignore attribute working?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried deleting the table? If you had it already created it won't delete existing columns.

Comment: Sure, I delete the table every time I do a try. Seems that some others attributes are not considered, i.e. if I set "Cascade" attribute in field decoration when I execute the GetAllWithColumns an exception is thrown telling that the attribute is unknown...